# How to get the extension of a file in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to alert that "Please enter file .docx and .pdf" so I need the extension of the file...

```
 $(".upload").click(function () {

 var filename = $("#file").val();
 var extension = " ";
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a working example. Just use `.split()` on the provided path

```
$(".upload").click(function () {

  var filename = $("#file").val();

  var pathParts = filename.split('/');   // Split the path on '/': ['path', 'to', 'file.ext']
  var filename  = pathParts.pop();       // Take the last element. This is a file name: 'file.ext'
  var filenameParts filename.split('.'); // Split the file name on the '.': ['file', 'ext']
  var extension = filenameParts[1];      // Take the extension: 'ext'
});
```

Or you can do it in one line:

```
var extension = filename.split('/').pop().split('.')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Split function

```js
$("#file").val('file.ext');

$("#upload").click(function () {
   var filename = $("#file").val();
   var aux = filename.split('.');
   var extension = aux[aux.length -1].toUpperCase();
   
   if(extension === 'DOC'
      || extension === 'DOCX'
      || extension === 'PDF'
      ){
      alert('Valid extension.');
   }else{
      alert('Invalid extension: ' + extension + '. Only: DOC, DOCX, PDF are allowed.');
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='file'/>
<button id='upload'>Upload</button>
```